# Telecommunication CubeSats

Tags: low-earth-orbit, cubesat, communication-satellite

Does anyone know of any company that is using CubeSats for telecommunication services or is this a new idea not yet implemented into the commercial arena?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by Telecom.

Amsat has a two-way radio transponder cubesat, called [Fox.](https://www.amsat.org/meet-the-fox-project/) , for amateur radio operators.

[AIS signals](http://www.spacequest.com/ais-payloads/sts-300-ais-receiver) from ships can be received and retransmitted.

There are other applications that are on going as well, although these are the two projects with which I am familiar.